# Erase Blank Json Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a rails backend that recieves JSON that (when parsed) looks like:

```
[
   {"kind"=>"Magazine", "price"=>["$20.99"]},
   {"kind"=>"Book", "price"=>"", "title"=>""}
]
```

Basically what I want to do is for each kind of product (e.g. Magazine or book), if all other attributes except for the **kind** key are blank, then don't save that array key/value. So in my example, Magazine would stay in the array, but the Book kind would be deleted (because both attributes price and title are blank.

I know I could loop through with something like (list is the parsed JSON before):

```
list.each do |l|
    if l["kind"] == "Magazine"
       if l["price"].blank?
          # THEN DELETE THIS ITERATION
       end
    end
end
```

but this seems very repetitive and not clean. How do I do this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this would involve using [Array#reject!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) to remove the unwanted lines.   You can also extract just the values, remove the blank ones, and count the remaining values... making sure that 'kind' is one of them...

```
list.reject! {|item| item.values.reject(&:blank?).size < 2 && item['kind'].present?}
```

Notice the difference between `reject` and `reject!` ... one returns a new hash while the `!` method modifies it in place.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `Hash` with a method to remove blank values (this supports nested hashes also):

```
class Hash
  def delete_blank
    delete_if{|k, v| v.blank? or v.instance_of?(Hash) && v.delete_blank.blank?}
  end
end
```

And after the blank values are removed, if there is only one key left and it is `kind`, then remove the array element:

```
list.each do |l|
  l.delete_blank
end
list.reject! {|l| l.key?('kind') && l.length < 2}

#=> [{"kind"=>"Magazine", "price"=>["$20.99"]}]
```

Comment: extending Hash and deleting keys sounds like it has too many side effects.